# Problems using a class without source code in Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Let me give you some context. In my university, they use the BlueJ IDE for java learning purpose. I'm trying to use other "more-professional" tool in order to learn more about java development.

In BlueJ, if you drop a java .class file (without its respective .java file) in a package, BlueJ lets you use that class and reference it from another classes. When I try to do the same in Visual Studio it give me the error: `Polygon cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)`. In addition, the classpath options (the referenced libraries option) doesn't let me include a .class file, only .jar (I have created a .jar from the .class file and didn't work tho).

BlueJ show these .class like this:

[image: bluej project schema]

This is the directory hierarchy:

[image: project directory]

And for the last, one of the .java files that gives the error How can I use these classes without the source file? Just Like in BlueJ. If it is not possible, could I do it in IntelliJ? Because I'm trying and still cannot do it.

```
package pract5;

/**
 * Clase NodePol: representacion de una estructura que asocia 
 * un dato (de tipo Polygon) y el enlace al dato siguiente.
 * Se usa para implementar secuencias enlazadas de poligonos.
 *
 * @author PRG - Practica 5
 * @version Curso 2022/23
 */
public class NodePol {
    // COMPLETAR DECLARACION ATRIBUTOS
    
    Polygon data;
    NodePol next;
    /**
     * Crea un NodePol con dato p y que no tiene siguiente.
     * @param p Polygon, dato del nuevo nodo.
     */
    public NodePol(Polygon p) {
        data = p; 
        // o de manera equivalente: this(p, null); 
    }
    
    /**
     * Crea un NodePol con dato p, enlazado a un nodo preexistente n. 
     * @param p Polygon, dato del nuevo nodo.
     * @param n NodePol, nodo siguiente al que enlazar el nuevo nodo.
     */
    public NodePol(Polygon p, NodePol n) {
        data = p;
        next = n;    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not using Visual Studio (a full-fledged IDE for C, C++ and C#), you're using Visual Studio Code. In any case, in general you need to add the root directory containing the .class file to the classpath, and make sure that the .class itself is in the right nested directories matching its class names.

Comment: Honestly, Visual Studio isn't the best tool for Java development -- it's really geared towards .NET development. I would suggest using IntelliJ IDEA if you want something truly made for Java development with the corresponding tooling integrated.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have done it and it keeps the same...

Comment: *I'm trying to use other "more-professional" tool in order to learn more about java development.* That's a laudable aim, but actually you'd learn more if you dropped all IDEs. You can go back to them later

Comment: Surprised they still teach Java, universities do lag behind the tech world. Could never understand why BlueJ was used when getting used to an IDE seemed to be a significant part of the workload with Java. I use VS Code for web dev but Netbeans, Eclipse, and IntelliJ are by far the most common IDEs used for Java, and I agree with @akseli that the latter is my preferred option. No IDE; then Ant, Maven or Gradle are the build tools to look at, but they have their own learning curve. CLI tooling gets messy quickly irl but I agree with g00se re learning.

Comment: Also, make sure you know what package the class occupies. That can be determined by `javap <full path to the class file>` at the command line, which will print the fully-qualified class name

Comment: *by given information, the Polygon.class must be in folder called parct5* You mean `pract5`. But how do you know that is the correct package for an already-compiled class? One way to know your assertion is correct would be if the compiler *did not* complain. But it does

Comment: A .class is a compiled Java class, you don't need its source code to use it, the IDE used doesn't matter (they all use javac compiler below the hood). The only problem I see here is that you don't have the file in your classpath or the package directory is incorrect as already mentioned in previous comments. Can you show us where exactly you drop the .class in BlueJ for it to work?

Comment: *you must refresh your browser* The name of the package is a triviality. It's my main point that's the important one

Comment: @m0skit0 It's all on the same directory, as same as I did in BlueJ

Comment: @a2k42 BlueJ is useful because getting started in Java with a "Hello World" app requires numerous cognitive leaps over various concepts, all without purposeful use at that point in the learning curve. [BlueJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJ), [JShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JShell), and [JEP 445, Unnamed Classes and Instance Main Methods (Preview)](https://www.infoq.com/news/2023/05/beginner-friendly-java/) are all ways to ease that burden, to make learning Java easier.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio Code, but [this page of doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project) seems to talk about adding libraries to a Java project.

Comment: Did you test this one on BlueJ or you're referring to previous assignments you did?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, I tested on BlueJ the same .class files and it works

Comment: This is possible, but IDEs are generally not set up to allow this by default. In professional development, individual compiled class files are _not_ commonly used. Dependencies are distributed in JARs, and are usually managed using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle. My sincere advice is to follow the process and use the tools recommended by your instructor. Solving this problem in another IDE won’t teach you much about professional workflows and could distract from learning core programming concepts.